# iTunes Connect - Getting Rejected

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

So, I have tried to upload my application to the iTunes Connect, but it gets rejected.

> 2.11
>   Apps that encourage excessive consumption of alcohol or illegal substances, or encourage minors to consume alcohol or smoke cigarettes, will be rejected

**My application**
So the application I am creating is a Drinking game application. It contains "I have never/Never have I ever", and some spinning bottle look-a-like. I have several view controllers that contains rules on how to play each game.

After a search on AppStore for "Drinking Game" I get over 500 results of games. **So how come that theirs game gets approved, but not my game**.

I do not have any question in the "Never have I ever" game that asks for alchol, cigarettes or any usage of drugs, but the other games does.

**EDIT:**
I submitted an appeal to the Apple Review board, and got this back:

> 2.18 - Apps that encourage excessive consumption of alcohol or illegal substances, or encourage minors to consume alcohol or smoke
>   cigarettes, will be rejected

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone here can help you.  Have you gone through Apple's appeal process?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer - Yes, I have.

Comment: It seems like You have to argue with them (Apple Review Team).

Comment: They are really the only people to whom you can appeal.

Comment: I suppose you could point out other very similar apps and see if they get taken down... but then you could be rejected for creating an app that isn't especially unique and of which there are many versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not Apple support.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly obvious isn't it?:

> 2.18 - Apps that encourage excessive consumption of alcohol or illegal substances, or encourage minors to consume alcohol or smoke
>   cigarettes, will be rejected

You have implemented what is a very well known drinking game.

The fact that other games have slipped through is not really relevant. You *could* try pointing to these and ask for clarification as to why they are approved but yours isn't, but the most likely response is the other games also get pulled.

Comment: I already asked, and they said back: From Apple
2.18 - Apps that encourage excessive consumption of alcohol or illegal substances, or encourage minors to consume alcohol or smoke cigarettes, will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Since `2.18` appears to address an issue with *minors* you might want to try to re-submit it making it 17+ or higher (if possible).

Hope that helps :)